# Daemon's open file limit is reached even though the system limits have been increased

Tags: debian, daemon, limit, open-files

I am running Debian wheezy. File limits are increased to 100000 for every user.
`ulimit -a` and `ulimit -Hn` / `-Sn` show me the right amounts of maximum open file limits even in screen.
But for some reason I am not able to to have more than ~4000 connections / open files.

from `sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 500 65000
net.core.somaxconn = 81920
```

Output of `ulimit -a`:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 256639
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 999999
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 256639
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

for example redis:

client: benchmark with 100 clients

```
Writing to socket: Connection reset by peer
Writing to socket: Connection reset by peer
Writing to socket: Connection reset by peer
Writing to socket: Connection reset by peer
Error: Connection reset by peer
```

server info:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> info clients
-Clients
connected_clients:4005
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0
```

Java:

```
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to open a socket.
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openSocketChannel(Unknown Source)
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to open a socket.
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openSocketChannel(Unknown Source)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to open a socket.
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
```

`ls -l /proc/[id]/fd | wc -l` shows ~4000 descriptors

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? From what program?

Comment: for example redis. I added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two settings that limit the number of open files: a per-process limit, and a system-wide limit. The system-wide limit is set by the `fs.file-max` sysctl, which can be configured in [`/etc/sysctl.conf`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sysctl.conf&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en) (read at boot time) or set on the fly with the [`sysctl`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sysctl&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en) command or by writing to `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`. The per-process limit is set by `ulimit -n`.

The per-process limit is inherited by each process from its parent. A default value can be set in [`/etc/security/limits.conf`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sysctl.conf&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en), but this only applies to interactive sessions, not to daemons started at boot time. It will apply to a daemon only if it's started via an interactive session.

To increase (or decrease) per-process limits for a daemon, in general, edit its startup script and add a call to `ulimit` just before the daemon is started. The Debian redis package comes with a configuration setting in a separate file: `/etc/default/redis`. Comment out the `ULIMIT=` line and increase the value if necessary.

Comment: well thank you very much, this solved the redis problem. But I still got the problem with screen. I start a java process, do ulimit -n && ulimit -a and everything looks just fine. But at ~4000 the script crashes.

Comment: @SvenNeumann I wonder if your Java runtime has its own limit? Run `strace java Whatever.jar` and look at the last few lines: see if the program fails with EMFILE near the end.

Comment: Runs just fine without any fails.

Comment: @SvenNeumann Oh, by the way, are these TCP sockets? If so, this could also be due to having too many [sockets in TIME_WAIT state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726049/what-is-the-reason-for-time-wait-connection-increasing-in-java).

Comment: had a look over the sysctl.conf settings, turns out I forgot to set them right on this server. Redis works fine now, tested up to 10k connections.